# Shopping cart quantity rule that changes catalog prices?

Tags: magento-1.9

Does anyone know a way to create a shopping cart rule that will change the catalog prices?

Here is what we have setup. We have 5 levels of dealers, wholesale, Level 1, 2, 3, and 4. Each level gets a certain discount off wholesale depending on what level they are set at. Also each of these levels have quantity discounts.

- Wholesale - 0-4 items - 0% Off
- Level 1 - 5-9 items - 5% Off
- Level 2 - 10-14 items - 10% off
- Level 3 - 15-34 items - 12%
- Level 4 - 35+ items - 14%

Like I said each dealer is set to a certain level(setup as customer groups in Magento), and I have catalog rules in place that show the discounted price in the catalog for each of these levels. The dealers also get any discounts above what they are set as if they hit the quantity levels.

For example, a level 2 dealer's catalog prices show the wholesale cost minus 10%($308.70) throughout the site and on the cart. If this dealer orders 15-34 racks they will receive the extra 2% off, and same goes if they hit 35+ items. I am able to apply shopping cart rules to adjust the prices for this and it applies the discount as a percent off as a discount on the cart.

This is fine and dandy is most cases but we use an automated software that pulls the orders from Magento and posts them to Quickbooks. So when this discount is applied and pushed to QB, the extra discounts show up as a single line item discount instead of changing the cost of the actually product.

Having a shopping cart rule that changes the catalog price would remedy this issue.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: But the shopping cart rules are explicitely meant to take conditions from the cart, the catalog price must be ready before the cart is know. I do not think it can be made to work that way.

Comment: Yeah I realize that is how works but was hoping there would be a way to add a shopping cart rule that would either change the actual item price, or even the customer group, instead of just applying the discount as a single line item.

We are trying to automate as much as possible and with the way the discounts work, it pushes the item to QB at what ever the catalog price is set at and sets the extra discount as a single line item. And this will affect quite a few of the different accounting numbers in QB like cost of good sold.

Comment: The only way I see how to do that is to modify your export functionality to alter the item's output directly when it is sent and to drop the single line discout items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tip but I found an extension that would let me do this. It is called [Tiered Pricing Across Multiple Products](http://www.webshopapps.com/uk/extras/tiered-pricing-across-multiple-products.html#). This extension lets you use the tiered pricing setup but allows it to calculate the quantity across multiple products instead of that single item.